# C# DeflateStream Decompress with C++

Tags: c#, c++, inflate, deflate, deflatestream

I compressed data whit DeflateStream. I can decompress whit c#, but how can i decompress whit c++ (VS2013 RC)? I tried inflate whit zlib. Not worked.

Answer (score 1):

There are some headers and checksums to deal with. See

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/05/16/system-io-compression-capabilities-kim-hamilton.aspx